# Vectorization: How can I have only the set difference of the set of all elements before in a vector of vectors?

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I have a data.table like this:

```
dt=data.table(freq=c(4,3,2,1),elements=list(c('a','b','c'),
                                            c('a','d'),
                                            c('b','d'),
                                            c('b','d','c','e')))
   freq elements
1:    4    a,b,c
2:    3      a,d
3:    2      b,d
4:    1  b,d,c,e
```

I need the elements in each row to be only the set difference between the elements in that row and the joint of all elements of the sets before that row. In that way I would get something like:

```
   freq elements
1:    4    a,b,c
2:    3        d
3:    2       NA
4:    1        e
```

I could do this with a for that groups all elements till i-1 and get only the set difference but I would really like to know how to do it in a vectorized way, if it is possible.

thank you guys!

Comment: How did you get `e` in the last row?

Comment: Also, if you've got a non-vectorized solution, what is it?

Comment: Perhaps you could find the set difference of each element and of the cumulative set union? E.g. `Map(setdiff, dt$elements, head(Reduce(union, dt$elements, accumulate = TRUE, init = NULL), -1L))`

Comment: @alexis You could post that as an answer. I think that's a good way.

Comment: sorry guys already fixed the missing 'e'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you meant to have an 'e' in your last row of `dt`, and that `freq` is unique (if not, create a unique index, or use rows):

```
dt[, .(els = elements[[1]]), by = freq][
   , .(freq = freq[1]), by = els][
   , .(filtered = list(els)), by = freq][
   dt, on = 'freq']
#   freq filtered elements
#1:    4    a,b,c    a,b,c
#2:    3        d      a,d
#3:    2     NULL      b,d
#4:    1        e    b,d,e
```

Comment: Thank you Eddi, really good answer, I just don't understand the flow of the algorithm you just wrote, could you help me understanding it?

Comment: @AldoPareja try running it incrementally (adding one set of []s at a time) - the idea is quite simple - find the first freq for each element (2nd line above) - the rest is just rearranging it in the format you like

Comment: Really clean approach. Thoughts on formatting the chains with \n][ rather than ][\n? My editor only auto-indents properly for the former.

Comment: @ClaytonStanley tbh I really wish there was a way to do ]\n[. I'm still undecided on what the "best" syntax is.